# magento2 shows unwanted result in catalog search

Tags: magento-2.3

Magento 2 catalog search shows the unwanted result, instead of exact result, according to the search words.
Its magento 2 default behavior. Is there any way where we can fetch the exact result in catalog search page?
Please suggest solution, Thanks.